# how to change change html action to url action in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want use bootstrap Glyphicons for edit , delete and details as well. the default was given

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }, new { data_modal = "" })`

i want to modify it to use an icon to represent it so i edit it to

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }, new { data_modal = "" })" class="btn btn-warning">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

the error i got was

> Error  CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 
>   '<anonymous type: int id>' to 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary'
>
> Error  CS1503  Argument 4: cannot convert from 
>   ''<anonymous type: string data_modal>' to 'string'

Comment: Remove `new { data_modal = "" }` from `@Url.Action`. I assume you want to add that as a html attribute to the `<a>` element?

Comment: What should be the purpose of your 4th argument in the `Url.Action` method? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) it is the protocol, so as the first comment stated, you should definitely remove it.

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "item.UserID" },null )" data-modal="" class="btn btn-warning" > fourth parameter is **Protocol**, so you can not apply string value.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ActionLink()` method your adding  a `data-modal=""` attribute so to repeat that in your manual `<a>` element, it would be

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID }, )" class="btn btn-warning" data-modal="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Currently your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.String%29) of `Url.Action()` where the 4th parameter is the protocol (typeof `string`)

Answer (score 0):

As the error already stated the 3rd argument should be a RoutedValueDictionary and not an anonymous object.

The right overload for your function call is `Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID })` according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx).